# PHP: multiple spaces in PHP implode

Tags: php, html

I am imploding an array. Instead of using a "," or other delimiter I would like two spaces.

How can this be accomplished?

I've tried:

```
<div>{implode("  ", $my_array)}</div> // Condenses to one space.
<div>{implode("&nbsp; &nbsp;", $my_array)}</div> // Just prints out the &nbsp. I do not use hashes in my code.
```

Note: I do NOT use the # in my nbsp. StackOverflow renders them as spaces if I don't :P

Comment: have you tried just &nbsp; and not &#nbsp; (if you don't use hashes in the code why do you paste it here)

Comment: Looks like you are using some kind of templating engine which is probably converting your `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;` check the documentation for "escape sequences" or "raw output".

Comment: The `&nbsp;` renders just fine now :)

Comment: What template engine are you using here?

Comment: Actually, your implode is working, but for HTML, multiple basic space will be rendered as a simple space, its a fact. That's why, there is the solution with "non-breakable space" also known as `&nbsp;`. You can also try to use some special tags like `<pre>` in order to keep the initial format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `"\t"` (a horizontal tab) or just `"&nbsp &nbsp"` (two html spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your implode is working, but for HTML, multiple basic space will be rendered as a **single space**, its a fact.

That's why, there is the solution with "non-breakable space" also known as `&nbsp;`.

You can also try to use some special tags like `<pre>` in order to keep the initial format

Comment: Pretty sure you meant "single space" and not "simple space".